# Java, JFileChooser. Дублируется описание фильтра\фильтр файлов

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте! Сделал простое окно, где содержится одна кнопка. Она и открывает диалог. При каждом нажатии, появляется еще одна строчка в "Тип файла" списке.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
//ImageFilter1.java
public class ImageFilter1 extends FileFilter {
    private String description;
    private String[] extensions=null;
    private String extension=null;
//...
    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
}

//JChooserTest
public class JChooserTest{
//.....
        JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser();
        show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String[] exts = new String[]{".png",".jpg"};
                choose.setFileFilter(new ImageFilter1("Images: *.png *.jpg", exts));

                int returnVal = choose.showDialog(frame, "Attach");

                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = choose.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println("Opening: " + file.getName() + ".");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Open command cancelled by user.");
                }
            }
        });
    //.....
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите класс ImageFilter1 полностью

Answer (score 1):

А так?

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
        "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
            chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
```

см. [javax.swing.JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)

Comment: Спасибо за другой вариант применения фильтра. Я руководствовался этим: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

На другом форуме подсказали, была банальная ошибка. Фильтр применяется при нажатии на кнопку так как он в ActionListener,  вместо вне события.